# Plotly click event in Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly, jquery-click-event

I am trying to use plotly java script click event in  angular 2 project but it is returning the below error

Property 'on' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

```
let myPlot = document.getElementById('donutChartId');
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
console.log(data.points[0].label);
});
```

Angular build is failing because of this.

Answer (score 1):

`.on()` is a [jquery method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

If you are using Jquery in your application you may create a jquery object from selected element to use this method.

```
let myPlot = document.getElementById('donutChartId');

to

let myPlot = $(document.getElementById('donutChartId'));
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I tried that before but it says "Cannot find name '$"

Comment: Have you added types for jquery? you should have types installed something like this should be in your depenedcies for types "@types/jquery": "1.10.31",', and also actual jquery library should be part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Think it is more of a compilation error. But your code will work. If you are concerned on the error. You can create a child class for ES6 HTMLElement class. Add the below code above in your component.

```
class CustomHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  on(event_type, cb) {
  }
}
```

And type cast in element selection

`let myPlot =  <CustomHTMLElement>document.getElementById('donutChartId');`